# Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner'

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile-safari, appium-ios, safaridriver

When i am trying to install webdriverlauncher using appium on iOS, i am seeing the above error, However xcode build is succeeded. 
Xcode build is failing through appium. I changed bundle identifier manually in xcode, However it didn't understand from where **com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner** is invoking
Can anyone please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you trusted the app on your iOS device? To do so, go to 'Setting' -> 'General' -> 'Profile & Device Management'

Answer (score 0):

I solved using below methods,

As @Jade said make sure you trust the app in your device and follow below steps.

1. Navigate to appium-webdriveragent folder in Terminal
2. Run below commands

```
./Scripts/bootstrap.sh && npm i --package-lock-only && npm audit fix && ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh (These 2 lines are single command and it is optional)
```

```
xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=<udid>' -allowProvisioningUpdates GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0 test
```

This approach solved my issue.